# WPF Webcam component crashes under .NET 4.0

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-4.0, webcam, wpf-4.0

I've got a WPF webcam component's source-code from [Codeplex](http://wpfcap.codeplex.com/) that I'm trying to port from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.0.

Compiles just fine under both targets, but in the .NET 4.0 version, it crashes when running the app with a `System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception` at the line `moniker.BindToObject(bindCtx, null, ref filterId, out filterObject);` in this method:

```
internal static IBaseFilter CreateFilter(string filterMoniker)
        {
            object filterObject = null;
            IBindCtx bindCtx = null;
            IMoniker moniker = null;

            int n = 0;

            if (CreateBindCtx(0, out bindCtx) == 0)
            {
                if (MkParseDisplayName(bindCtx, filterMoniker, ref n, out moniker) == 0)
                {
                    Guid filterId = typeof(IBaseFilter).GUID;
                    try
                    {
                        moniker.BindToObject(bindCtx, null, ref filterId, out filterObject);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex+"");
                    }

                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(moniker);
                }
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(bindCtx);
            }
            return filterObject as IBaseFilter;
        }
```

Any idea why and how to fix it?

The camera is a [Genius Eye 110](http://www.geniusnet.com.tw/geniusOnline/online.portal?_nfpb=true&productPortlet_actionOverride=%2Fportlets%2FproductArea%2Fcategory%2FqueryPro&_windowLabel=productPortlet&productPortletproductId=510241&_pageLabel=productPage&test=portlet-action), and I'm working under Windows XP SP2.

Comment: Did you try to add to your app.config <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"> string?

Comment: @Eugene Cheverda I've just tried adding this in app.config, yet nothing changed: I still get the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the code, compiled it with 4.0 and it worked for me.  Are you sure that you have a webcam that your system knows about?  Perhaps you can check the device manager to verify.

If my camera is not plugged it, the program throws an exception similar to yours.

-Matt

Comment: Camera is a Genius Eye 110, connected and functional. Compiling and running on .NET 3.5 SP1 works, whereas on 4.0 throws the exception I was mentioning.